# No space left on device at path /tmp/rust_mozprofile when running selenium firefox test

Tags: ruby, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I'm using selenium 4-beta3 (but with selenium 3.14 I had the same error)

Driver configuration is next

```
Capybara.register_driver :remote do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:acceptInsecureCerts = true)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    url: "http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub",
    capabilities: caps
  )
end
```

Docker-compose file excerpt:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  firefox:
    depends_on:
    - selenium-hub
    environment:
    - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
    - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
    - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
#    - TMPDIR=/home/seluser/
    image: <via proxy from SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/node-firefox:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426>
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
    - 6902:5900
  selenium-hub:
    image: <via proxy from SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426 >
    ports:
    - 4442:4442
    - 4443:4443
    - 4444:4444
```

Whenever I tried to run test - it fails and firefox log lists this error:

```json
{
  "traceId": "896f73c51497bb215636151497801994",
  "spanId": "f26ae935f64f5878",
  "spanKind": "INTERNAL",
  "eventTime": 1620655881163418737,
  "eventName": "exception",
  "attributes": {
    "driver.url": "http://localhost:19528",
    "exception.message": "Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: No space left on device (os error 28) at path \"/tmp/rust_mozprofiletz7oB7\"\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3', revision: '5d108f9a67'\nSystem info: host: 'f8ad4b70c435', ip: '192.168.144.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.121-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_282'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: No space left on device (os error 28) at path \"/tmp/rust_mozprofiletz7oB7\"\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3', revision: '5d108f9a67'\nSystem info: host: 'f8ad4b70c435', ip: '192.168.144.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.121-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_282'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:128)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:63)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply(SessionSlot.java:143)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession(LocalNode.java:325)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.NewNodeSession.execute(NewNodeSession.java:52)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:192)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.security.RequiresSecretFilter.lambda$apply$0(RequiresSecretFilter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.execute(Node.java:240)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException",
    "logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory",
    "session.capabilities": "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\"}\n"
  }
}
```

When I examine firefox docker container - `/tmp` folder is empty.

---

`EDIT:`

I tried pointing to /dev/shm as tem dir and allocating enough memory

```
    environment:
    - TMPDIR=/dev/shm
    shm_size: 4g
```

and it worked - when viewing logs I see that firefox webdriver initialized properly, but now it lacks space in `/home/seluser/` directory

`dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/home/seluser/.cache/dconf': No space left on device.  dconf will not work properly.`

Answer (score 0):

Checked my Docker Desktop Resources - Disk image size was running out of space. I increased the space and test started working