# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException in Python Selenium using GeckoDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run Selenium on Python using GeckoDriverManager.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

service = FirefoxService(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

It was working fine until the last 5 minutes but now when I run any program that contains it this exception is thrown:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to set preferences: Unable to write Firefox profile: No space left on device (os error 28)
```

What does that mean? I've searched a bit about this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: "No space left on device" Means you are out of disk space. Delete some files to make room.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608820/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-there-is-not-enough-space-on-the-disk-er

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472887/no-space-left-on-device-at-path-tmp-rust-mozprofile-when-running-selenium-firef

Comment: It can't be possible sir, I have 62.95 GB free in my ext4 partition and 48.61 in my home partition.

Comment: Oh, I understand thanks to your last link. I realized that my `/tmp/` folder was full so deleted its content using https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107003. Thank you sir.

Comment: If you have a separate partition for `/tmp/` then that would explain it.